# Do I need a new tire?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

I noticed I had a flat in one of my tires so I made a trip to the nearest shop to get air now my tire has a ring around it showing where it rubbed against the rim!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqSGj.jpg)
[image]

Comment: The guy told if he put more air it would pop and that I should get a new one but is the condition really that bad to the point my tire will pop while driving?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Usually, if you've driven on the rim and it's cut into the sidewall of the tire, it's time for a new tire. By doing this, you've seriously damaged the integrity of the sidewall. I can't see the image at work to give you better advice, so I'll leave this as a comment.

Comment: I fixed the image it should show now.

Comment: That isn't the problem. My work blocks images from several sources, this being one of them.

Comment: Also, if you are driving around with it seriously under-inflated (since the guy at the shop didn't want to burst it, and from your picture it looks visibly under-inflated where it touches the ground) it will tend to overheat as you drive, which will weaken it more - and an under-inflated tire will affect the car's handling as well. Bottom line - get a new tire ASAP!

Answer (score 3):

That tire you definitely need to replace, the safety of you, your family and other road users is not worth the risk.

Comment: I will get it replaced but how is the mark on the outer tire dangerous??

Comment: That amount of flexing on the sidewall weakens the plies (or strengthening bands / material) in the sidewall. Failure could happen at any time, so fit the spare and get that one replaced.

Comment: 3 separate contributors on here have said "replace the tire", what don't you understand?

Comment: Agree with the answer

Answer (score 3):

Sidewall damages are most dangerous one. The tires weakest spot is Sidewall. If you drive with this tire at high speed it can start to wobble and pop out of nowhere. Since it won't be a tiny hole that will lose air gradually, but a serious pop you might lose control and crash. Just change the tire.